# Running Shiny app using Docker on DigitalOcean

Tags: docker, shiny, ip, port, digital-ocean

I try to run a Shiny app on a remote server (here DigitalOcean) using Docker.

First, I created a package for my app as a .tar.gz file. Then:

Create the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM thinkr/rfull

COPY myapp_*.tar.gz  /myapp.tar.gz

RUN R -e "install.packages('myapp.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')"

COPY Rprofile.site /usr/local/lib/R/etc

EXPOSE 3838
CMD ["R", "-e myapp::run()"]
```

Create the following Rprofile.site

```
local({
   options(shiny.port = 3838, shiny.host = "0.0.0.0")
})
```

Then I build the image using

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

I push the image to DockerHub using

```
docker tag myapp myrepo/myapp:latest
docker push myrepo/myapp
```

I connect to my droplet on DigitalOcean

```
eval $(docker-machine env mydroplet)
```

I create a container from my image on Dockerhub

```
docker run -d -p 3838:3838 myrepo/myapp
```

So far it seems to work fine. No message error and I got expected messages when I run `docker logs mycontainer`

The problem is that **I do not know how to actually access the running container**. When I connect to the droplet IP, I got nothing (`This site can’t be reached`). If use

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' mycontainer
```

I got an IP, it seems to be a local one ('172.17.0.2').

When I run `docker ps` here is what I got

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
6d4195XXXX        myrepo/myapp   "R '-e myapp::ru…"   10 days ago         Up 10 days          0.0.0.0:3838->3838/tcp, 8787/tcp   determined_brown
```

So the question is: **how can I run my dockerized shiny app on my droplet IP address?**

Comment: the `172.17.0.2` address is the internal address of the container itself, so not something to worry about. The `-p 3838:3838` should map port `3838` of the host to port `3838` of the container, which should make it accessible on the public IP address of the droplet.

I'd recommend trying if running a different image and publishing its port works (to narrow down if it's an issue with your image or with the droplet or its network configuration). For example `docker run -d -p 4000:80 nginx:alpine`, then try accessing `http://<droplet ip>:4000`

Comment: @thaJeztah the nginx container works. So it seems it might be an issue on my side... The strange think is that when I call `docker logs mycontainer` it seems to be working fine... It cannot identify any error in the logs

Comment: no ideas directly. Does the app log anything at all? (i.e. does it log to stdout/stderr, other wise Docker won't be able to pick up the logs?). Also suspecting that the `CMD` may need to have `-e` separate in the JSON array; `CMD ["R", "-e", "myapp::run()"]`

Comment: yes the log works fine. I got the expected messages in it, as if the app is running correctly.

Comment: share us the result of docker ps

Comment: You could check if the docker host has published (started listening) the port 3838 using this command: `sudo netstat -apn | grep 3838`, another thing I would also do is to try a different publishing port when creating the container like this: `docker run -d -p 4000:3838 myrepo/myapp` and check if `http://<droplet ip>:4000` responds

Comment: @JRichardsz added the results of `docker ps` in the question

Comment: could you try this : `curl localhost:3838` or `telnet localhost 3838` inside your droplet?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added the firewall rule to allow connections to 3838 port.

https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/firewalls/resources/troubleshooting/

Comment: inbound and outbound TCP are set to "All ports". That should be ok right?

Comment: Can you check the output of following command

`sudo ufw status`

if 3838 port is not in the list, then allow it using

`sudo ufw allow 3838/tcp`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to publish the port, which is what you already do.
Second, you need to access the IP address of the host machine where there port is published.
The easiest way is probably to check the output of `docker-machine env mydroplet` and use this IP, together with your published port.